# Unable to get complete user information from Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I have the following lines of code for enabling the extended permissions from user side on Facebook.

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'user_activities,user_education_history,user_events,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_religion_politics,user_work_history') );
```

When I get the information, I only see fields related to education,hometown,location, religion_politics, and work history.

Rest of the fields are missing. I really don't know why.

Comment: I think there is a limit to how much you can have access to. Also make sure that you've allowed access when testing

Answer (score 0):

Try the permission user_about_me that will get the majority of the requests that you want, not all. Also you generally can't get all the information you want from one request instead of just

```
$facebook->api('/me');
```

You need to do several requests e.g

```
$facebook->api('/me/events');
$facebook->api('/me/likes');
```

There are some examples here.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/